# Jquery multiple unwanted rotation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, rotation

I have a problem with my code. I have multiple blocks on my page, and i want each block to rotate separately of the other block. This jQuery code manages that, but also updates variable "rotation" so the next block rotates for 180 + 180*n ('n' = times current block rotated)

I presume that the problem lies within variable rotation, but don't know any workaround.

```js
var rotation = 0;
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
  $(this).css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)'
  });
};

$('.strijela').click(function() {
  rotation += 180;
  $(this).rotate(rotation);
});
```

```css
.strijela {
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="strijela">this should rotate once when clicked</div>
<div class="strijela">this should also rotate when clicked but only once.</div>

<p>
  problem is, the more you click on first block, second block will rotate that much more times and vice versa. I know it is because of the variable "rotation", but don't know how to solve that problem. Thank you.
</p>
```

In conclusion, I need 'n' separate blocks that will spin for only 180°, not for 180*n

http://jsfiddle.net/Lbq3K/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you're incrementing the global `rotation` variable, so the rotation of any subsequent click on any element is multiplied by the number of previous clicks.

To fix this you could associate a `rotation` value on a per-element basis using a `data` attribute, like this:

```js
$.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
  return $(this).css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)'
  });
};

$('.strijela').click(function() {
  var rotation = $(this).data('rotation') || 0;
  rotation += 180;
  $(this).rotate(rotation).data('rotation', rotation)
});
```

```css
.strijela {
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="strijela">this should rotate once when clicked</div>
<div class="strijela">this should also rotate when clicked but only once.</div>
```

Also note that I added a `return` statement to your `$.rotate` plugin so that you can continue to chain methods from the response.

Comment: I didn't even thought about "return", not only you solved the problem, you actually taught me something. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is you can use the `click` count on the element using `data-click` attribute and `attr()` jQuery.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$("div").attr("data-click", 0);
$("div").on("click", function() {
  var click = $(this).attr("data-click");
  click++;
  $(this).attr("data-click", click);
  $(this).css({
    "transform": "rotate(" + 180 * click + "deg)"
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

div:after {
  content: attr(data-click);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
```